# How to pass a Profile object as an argument to ChatPage?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I'm coding a Tinder like application but I'm having dificulties passing the created profile object to the ChatPage.
When using

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ChatPage(profile: profile),
                ));
```

an error pops up:

> The argument type 'Profile (where Profile is defined in d:\Documentos\UFF\LabMoveis\flutter\V8\grupoverde20212\lib\src\models\profile.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Profile (where Profile is defined in d:\Documentos\UFF\LabMoveis\flutter\V8\grupoverde20212\lib\src\model\profile.dart)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
> profile.dart(8, 7): Profile is defined in d:\Documentos\UFF\LabMoveis\flutter\V8\grupoverde20212\lib\src\models\profile.dart
> profile.dart(1, 7): Profile is defined in d:\Documentos\UFF\LabMoveis\flutter\V8\grupoverde20212\lib\src\model\profile.dart

If anyone could help me, the code is below:

**ChatTab**

```
// This tab shows the matches, so the user can chat with them. Also, the map can be accessed from here.

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gather/src/widgets/tabs/chat.dart';
import '../../models/profile.dart';
import '../../tools/cloudstore.dart';
import '../../tools/general.dart';
import '../miscellaneous/awaitsign.dart';
import '../miscellaneous/errorsign.dart';
import '../pages/chat.dart';

class ChatTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final Profile userProfile;

  const ChatTab({required this.userProfile, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatTabState createState() => _ChatTabState();
}

class _ChatTabState extends State<ChatTab> {
  List<Profile> profiles = <Profile>[];

  ListTile _tile(Profile profile) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(profile.name,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 20,
          )),
      // subtitle: Text(subtitle),
      leading: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30, backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile.photoUrl)),
      onTap: () {
        print('show chat page.');
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ChatPage(profile: profile),
                ));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stream = getBonds(userId: widget.userProfile.id, bonds: ['match']);
      return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          final AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snap = snapshot;
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const AwaitSign();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const ErrorSign();
          }
          if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(child: Text("No matches for you."));
          }
          profiles.clear();
          return FutureBuilder<int>(
                future: getProfilesFromDocs(
                    docs: snapshot.data!.docs, buffer: profiles),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Stack(children: [
                      ListView.separated(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        itemCount: profiles.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return _tile(profiles[index]);
                        },
                        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                            const Divider(),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        right: 10,
                        bottom: 10,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/map', arguments: {
                              'profile': widget.userProfile,
                              // 'profiles': profiles
                              'stream': stream,
                              'snapshot': snap
                            });
                          },
                          child: const Icon(Icons.pin_drop_outlined))
                        )
                      ]);
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const ErrorSign();
                  }
                  return const AwaitSign();
                },
              );
        });
  }
}
```

**Profile Class**

```
    class Profile {
      String id, name, photoUrl, designation, bio;
      List<String>? tags;
      GeoPoint? location;
    
      Profile(
          {required this.id,
          required this.name,
          this.bio = 'No bio',
          this.designation = 'No designation',
          this.photoUrl = defaultProfilePictureUrl,
          this.location,
          this.tags});
    
      factory Profile.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Profile(
            id: json['id'] as String,
            name: json['name'] as String,
            bio: json['bio'] as String,
            designation: json['designation'] as String,
            tags: List.from(json['tags'] as Iterable));
      }
    
      factory Profile.fromQueryDocument(QueryDocumentSnapshot qds) {
        return Profile(
            id: qds.id,
            name: qds['name'] as String,
            bio: qds['bio'] as String,
            designation: qds['designation'] as String,
            tags: List.from(qds['tags'] as Iterable));
      }
    }
```

**ChatPage**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
// import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gather/src/model/profile.dart';
// import 'package:gather/src/widgets/miscellaneous/search.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  final Profile profile;
  const ChatPage({Key? key, required this.profile}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  // final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Map<String, dynamic>? data;

  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  Future<void> callback() async {
    if (_messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _firestore.collection('messages').add({
        'text': _messageController.text,
        'from': data!['profile'].id,
      });
      _messageController.clear();
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data ??= ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.data!.docs;

                List<Widget> messages = docs
                    .map((doc) => Message(
                          from: doc['from'],
                          text: doc['text'],
                          me: data!['profile'].id == doc['from'],
                        ))
                    .toList();

                return ListView();
              },
            )),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Escreva sua Mensagem",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    controller: _messageController,
                  ),
                ),
                SendButton(
                  text: "Send",
                  callback: () {},
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SendButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback callback;

  const SendButton({Key? key, required this.text, required this.callback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        child: Text(text, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
        onPressed: callback);
  }
}

class Message extends StatelessWidget {
  final String from, text;
  // final String text;

  final bool me;

  const Message(
      {Key? key, required this.from, required this.text, required this.me})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment:
          me ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          from,
        ),
        Material(
          color: me ? Colors.teal : Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          elevation: 6.0,
          child: Container(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15.0),
            child: Text(
              text,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different definitions of `Profile`.

```
// in ChatTab
import '../../models/profile.dart';

// in ChatPage
import 'package:gather/src/model/profile.dart';
```

If both of these are in the same package, please note **models** vs **model** (no **s**)